# Is there a tool take a list of software packages and convert to SBoM (pref SPDX)?

Tags: spdx

I have a system from which I got a list of installed packages.  I can't run any of the automated tools because it's an embedded Timesys Linux installation with BusyBox, but I do have a list of the installed packages and their versions.  I need a tool that will take that list and create either SPDX or CyberDX SBoM output.

Tried manually creating an SPDX file, but that's tedious and time-consuming.  Automated scanners don't detect the Timesys Linux distribution.